# Paypal API subscription curl sandbox catalog products Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions

Tags: api, curl, paypal, subscription

This question is about paypal API catalog when try to create a production and to do a subscription.

I'm following this tutorial https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/

I'm able to get my token, but trying to create a product I get "Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions"

Here my code

```
// GET TOKEN
$paypalcurl = 'curl -v https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Accept-Language: en_US" -u "'.($paypal_client_id.':'.$paypal_client_secret).'" -d "grant_type=client_credentials"';
$ptoken_result = json_decode(exec($paypalcurl.' 2>&1'),true);
$ptoken = $ptoken_result['access_token'];

// CREATE PRODUCTI AND GET PRODUCT ID
$paypalcurl_create_prodct = 'curl -v -X POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/catalogs/products \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer '.$ptoken.'" \
-d \'{
  "name": "Video Streaming Service test",
  "description": "Video streaming service",
  "type": "SERVICE",
  "category": "SOFTWARE",
  "home_url": "https://www.example.com/"
}\'';
$pcreate_result = json_decode(exec($paypalcurl_create_prodct.' 2>&1'),true);

if ( ADMIN_PASS == 1 ) { echo str_replace(',',',<br>',var_export($pcreate_result,true)); }
```

Here the result

```
array ( 'name' => 'NOT_AUTHORIZED',
'message' => 'Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions.',
'debug_id' => 'f7d1051f9daf3',
'details' => array ( 0 => array ( 'issue' => 'PERMISSION_DENIED',
'description' => 'You do not have permission to access or perform operations on this resource.',
),
),
'links' => array ( 0 => array ( 'href' => 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#NOT_AUTHORIZED',
'rel' => 'information_link',
'method' => 'GET',
),
),
)
```

What I'm I missing ?

Comment: `$ptoken_result = json_decode(exec($paypalcurl.' 2>&1'),true);` what scopes does this result contain?  have you waited at least 9 hours after enabling Subscriptions for the ClientID's sandbox app in https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications ?

Comment: @PrestonPHX ok thanks, i saw no where written that I'd have to wait 9 hours, but yes now it works ;)

Comment: You don't normally, but if you have an access token generated from before the response with those scopes will be cached

Answer (score 0):

After the comment I realize that it was simply a delay.

1- go to https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/

2- click on the app you created

3- there is a checkmark Accept paymentsEnable one-time and subscription payments. Advanced options and CLICK on "Advanced options"

4- checkmark "Billing agreements" and "Future payments" and save

5- wait some hours

6- voilà!